# Files are synchronized though TFS branches

Tags: tfs

I'm working with VS 2010 and TFS 20xx(not sure version here, but at least: version <= 2010).

I've a main branch, which I've made two dev branches from. The problem I now have encountered is that files are being synchronized through these branches.

Branch hierarchy:
Main branch
 - Dev branch 1
 - Dev branch 2

Eg. if i change item xxxx.aspx in Dev branch 1, the change takes place in the other two branches as well. I've never experienced this before. It started to appear when i created branch dev 2.

What setting could be the cause of this?

Comment: I would guess at your Workspace Mappings. What do you mean by "the change takes place"? Is this a pending change, or when committed?

Comment: Does it mean without any interaction from you the changes are merged into the other branches? Please check the history, there should be the changesets of the merges and who did it. Maybe there is an automatic process running in your environment.

Comment: DaveShaw: "What do you mean by "the change takes place"? "
I mean, the same file changes automatically in the other two branches, only by saving the file.

Comment: @MikeR no interaction other than saving the file, meaning: i don't click merge. The changeset shows no merging.

Comment: Does the changes to the files in other branches happen locally? Or does that get checkedin as well?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I solved this issue by simply removing all my local files. Not a neat solution though did solve the issue.